# Strange row displayed during SQL Query on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation

I'm new to Data Analytics, taking the Coursera program.

For an exercise on BigQuery, query a public data (nyc citibike trips), I tried to use the CONCAT function to pull together 2 columns(start station name and end station name) to create a new column titled Route, and count the frequency of the trips. The query i wrote was:

```sql
SELECT
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name, " to", end_station_name) AS Route,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips` 
GROUP BY
  usertype,start_station_name,end_station_name
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC
LIMIT 
  10
```

But the problem is that the summary result. The first row is empty apart from "to" under the Route column, with a very huge count number.

Help what am i doing wrong. I have attached a screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnj1Q.png)

Comment: **citibike_trips** table seems to have noises which most colmuns are **null**s or empty string.   just add **WHERE usertype <> ''** condition in your query and try it again.

Comment: That's true about the noise in the table, you have helped me so much. Because after I checked the count of the usertype, it wasn't the same count for the start and end station. Apparently the end has a lot of blank cells - the same amount that's resulting in the empty 'to' rows in my summary results. Thank you!

Comment: see also comments for https://stackoverflow.com/q/72089859/5221944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a few queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
WHERE start_station_name = '';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
WHERE end_station_name = '';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
WHERE start_station_name IS NULL;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
WHERE end_station_name IS NULL;
```

If you find a few, you have the reason why you get that result. I'd regard this as a data quality problem ...

Comment: I think you have helped me figure it out!, and you are right there are some data quality problems. So the first 2 queries resulted in a total count of 5,828,994 of blank cells. And its the same count that's showing the empty 'to' rows in my summary results. Thank you so much! My goodness you have said me hours of pondering what the problem was.